# Next.js 13 Static site generation : cache-control & index.txt

Tags: javascript, next.js, cache-control, next.js13

Using Next.js 13,

I have my build in a bucket.

I want to force my user's browser to get the latest build of my generated static site. The problem is for each folder/page of the website there is an index.txt that is cached for 1 hour in the browser and it seems like an important file and plays a big part of an update/rebuild. this file isn't affected by the custom generateBuildId() in `next.config.js`.

---

trying to avoid first, setting the cache in the bucket for the files

I made a script that rewrite every path in every file that has index.txt, to add query param of the latest version to it.

So, i execute post-build a bash script (that finds index.txt and replace it by index.txt?v={my version here}):

```
find out -type f -exec grep -q "index.txt" {} \; -exec sed -i '' -e "s/index.txt/index.txt%3Fv=$(date +%s)/g" {} \;
```

my `out/_next/static/chunks/139-72884d103bad554b.js` gets updated..

But the browser gets `404` trying to get these files with an encoded URL, like:
`mywebsite.com/index.txt%3Fv=1234567`

---

Is there Any way in Next.js 13 to SSG rebuild and apply new version to all files (including .txt)?

Or, some way to add `?v={buildId}` to all assets dependencies (and the browser doesn't encode it)?

Or any other way to force browsers to refetch after rebuild.

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, check your `generateStaticParams`. From the original `pages` directory, the `app` directory has now changed.

Remove the `params` block:

```
return results.map((result) => ({
  params: {
    slug: result.slug,
  }
}));
```

becomes

```
return results.map((result) => ({
  slug: result.slug,
}));
```